# Want to make custom Calendar like below

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, calendar

[image: Calender preview]
want to make above calendar which has three recyclerview. Frist has year. Second has month. according to second recyclerview selection it will show day/date.How to add this year,month,day date to all three recylerview.

Comment: Instead of asking how to make, search the web and try it. If any error occur, then ask how to resolve it.

Comment: Looks like nothing but a GridView, to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Init first year Recyclerview
2. checked default year(now year)
3. Init second month Recyclerview.
4. checked default month(now month)
5. How many days per month are acquired by month,and you can init third Recycleview.
6. checked default day(now day)
7. when the  first Recyclerview item click  changed second Recyclerview data.and changed third Recyclerview.

ok .I hope it can help you! thanks

Comment: Yes,it will help with the scenario but he need something custom recylerview what shown in the image.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the way for making custom calendar  first  i take current  day date from  calendar and just do below calculation

```
    private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
    Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
    int trailingSpaces = 0;
    int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
    int prevMonth = 0;
    int prevYear = 0;
    int nextMonth = 0;
    int nextYear = 0;

    int currentMonth = mm - 1;
    String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
    daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

    Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
            + daysInMonth + " days.");

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
    Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

    if (currentMonth == 11) {
        prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
        daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        nextMonth = 0;
        prevYear = yy;
        nextYear = yy + 1;
        Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
        prevMonth = 11;
        prevYear = yy - 1;
        nextYear = yy;
        daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        nextMonth = 1;
        Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    } else {
        prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
        nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
        nextYear = yy;
        prevYear = yy;
        daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
                + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
                + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    }

    int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

    Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
            + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
    Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
    Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

    if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
        if (mm == 2)
            ++daysInMonth;
        else if (mm == 3)
            ++daysInPrevMonth;

    // Trailing Month days
    for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
        Log.d(tag,
                "PREV MONTH:= "
                        + prevMonth
                        + " => "
                        + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                        + " "
                        + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
                        - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                        + i));
        list.add(String
                .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                        + i)
                + "-GREY"
                + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                + "-"
                + prevYear);
    }

    // Current Month Days
    for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
        if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
        } else {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
        }
    }

    // Leading Month days
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
        Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
        list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
    }
```